# Exact same question without answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I'm noticing that a specific user asked the same question twice:

- [Dojo Accordion style population](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522240/dojo-accordion-style-population)
- [Populating Dojo Accordion using lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523400/populating-dojo-accordion-using-lists)

The content of the question is exactly the same (minus the image). I was thinking of closing one of the two (probably the one without the image) as being a duplicate. However, when you mark it as a duplicate, the description says:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

Which isn't the case, so I was wondering what the correct action is in this case? Should I flag it, or still mark it as a duplicate?

---

Currently I voted to close it as a duplicate for even another question he asked:

- [Populating Dojo AccordionContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502953/populating-dojo-accordioncontainer)

Which has been answered already (from the same user again), but what should I do if that question wasn't there?

I also noticed that the user in the first two questions is different as well, is that a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark it as a duplicate.

There's some logic preventing directing new users who legitimately have the same question to an old abandoned question with no answers.  That doesn't apply to the *same* user asking the *same identical* question, either as policy or in the technical enforcement.  Probably the questions are just different enough to confuse the automated logic... but we know better.

Comment: So I may close questions as a duplicate as well, even though they don't have answers? The description of the duplicate close reasons is confusing me a bit.

Comment: I was just wondering about this too, because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774846/is-it-possible-to-change-the-default-documentation-header-in-visual-studio-with/29775354#29775354. The linked question doesn't have an accepted answer... It certainly is a duplicate, but if the older question doesn't have an accepted answer, should it still be marked as a dupe?

Comment: @DrewJordan: Yes, there's a lot of value to future readers to having all the best answers collected in one place.  You should put your most complete answer on the "main" question even though it is older.  What you have now is little more than a signpost to a newer closed question, and very likely to be deleted as "Not an Answer".